# position_dodge() does not seem to work with stat_summary() and x variables with different fill groups

Tags: r

Using `stat_summary(geom = "bar) + stat_summary(geom = "errorbar")` does not seem to work with `position_dodge()`, in the case of `x` values with varying numbers of condition groups.

I am trying to make a (what should be straightforward) barplot with `ggplot2`. My data has a number of different samples (x variable), and some of these samples also have a fill (`condition`) variable ("Scr" or "shRNA") while others don't (`condition = NA`). When I attempt to plot these data using the `stat_summary` wrappers to make bar plots with error bars, the `position_dodge` function for errorbars only works on samples that do not have different fill groups. The `stat_summary(geom = "barplot")` seems to be functional, because the separate bars do show up, but their error bars are not aligned.

```
test <- data.frame(Sample = c(rep("A",6),rep("B",3)),
                   Target = c(rep("GENE1",9)),
                   val = c(1.1,1.2,1.15,.5,.6,.7,.95,1,1.05),
                   condition = c(rep("Scr",3),rep("shRNA",3),rep(NA,3)))



g <- ggplot(data=test,aes(x=Sample,y=val,fill=condition)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun.y = mean,position = position_dodge2(width=.5,preserve = "single"),color="black",width=.8) +
  stat_summary(geom = "errorbar", fun.data = mean_se, position = position_dodge2(width=.2,preserve = "single"),width=.2) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(mult = c(0,.2))) +
  #scale_fill_discrete(guide=guide_legend(title="",nrow=2))
```

I expect the `position_dodge()` argument in both `stat_summary()`'s to align error bars to the correct `x` position, regardless of whether or not that particular sample has one or two fill groups.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit confused about what you're trying to do. Why not use `geom_col`/`geom_bar` instead of `stat_summary`? I always prefer keeping data manipulation/summarisation and plotting separate.

This is what I'd do

```
library(tidyverse)
test %>%
    group_by(Sample, condition) %>%
    summarise(val.mean = mean(val), val.sd = sd(val)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(Sample, val.mean, fill = condition)) +
    geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8)) +
    geom_errorbar(
        aes(ymin = val.mean - val.sd, ymax = val.mean + val.sd),
        position = position_dodge(width = 0.8),
        width = 0.2)
```

[image]

Comment: This does indeed work, and after tinkering around with my original code, it looks like the problem is actually with using "position_dodge2()" instead of the original "position_dodge()". Using the original "position_dodge()" function works even with stat_summary() function. Thanks!